# Replace values with blanks in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have created a fictitious dataset test.df1. I want the values under the column "Exporter" to be blanks whenever the Year is 2018. The following code that I tried does not create blanks, rather creates NAs.

```
test.df1 <- data.frame("Year" = sample(2018:2020, 20, replace = TRUE), "Firm" = head(LETTERS, 5), "Exporter"= sample(c("Yes", "No"), 20, replace = TRUE))

test.df1$Exporter[test.df1$Year == 2018] <- " "
```

The above code also produces the following warning:

```
test.df1$Exporter[test.df1$Year == 2018] <- " "
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, test.df1$Year == 2018, value = c(2L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I understand that this is due to the column/variable named Exporter being a factor. But I am not sure exactly how I can take that into account to achieve my objective. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

On a related note, I was expecting the following code to replace all "Yes" values in the Exporter column with "P". But it changed nothing. What am I missing here?

```
levels(test.df1$Exporter)[levels(test.df1$Exporter == "Yes")] <- "P"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in R prior to 4.0, data.frame function will consider columns containing strings to be factors. To set the blanks, create the dataframe with stringsAsFactors set to FALSE:

```
test.df1 <- data.frame("Year" = sample(2018:2020, 20, replace = TRUE), "Firm" = head(LETTERS, 5), "Exporter"= sample(c("Yes", "No"), 20, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test.df1$Exporter[test.df1$Year == 2018] <- " "
```

You can then set Exporter to be a factor via as.factor:

```
test.df1$Exporter <- as.factor(test.df1$Exporter)
```

As an alternative, you can specify the factor levels when creating the dataframe, the stringsAsFactors set to `TRUE`:

```
test.df1 <- data.frame("Year" = sample(2018:2020, 20, replace = TRUE), "Firm" = head(LETTERS, 5), "Exporter"= factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), 20, replace = TRUE), levels = c('Yes', 'No', ' ')), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

On your second question, the levels are not changed because you are calling the levels function on the expression `test.df1$Exporter == "Yes"` which returns a logical array and doesn't have levels. If Exporter is a factor, you can instead use the following:

```
levels(test.df1$Exporter)[levels(test.df1$Exporter) == "Yes"] <- "P"
```

Note the difference to your original version, the interior levels is function is being called on the Exporter column, rather than a logical array of where the Exporter column is equal to 'Yes'

Comment: Thank you. I see my error as far as my first question is concerned. Regarding my first question, is there any way to achieve what I wanted to while keeping the Exporter column as a factor?

Comment: By the way, this default was changed as of R 4.0: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html

Comment: I've updated be answer to demonstrate keeping Exporter as a factor. This can be done via either encoding the character vector as a factor with is.factor, or during the generation of the initial dataframe via the levels argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `Exporter` column as factor you need to include it as one of the `levels` for that column.

```
test.df1 <- data.frame("Year" = sample(2018:2020, 20, replace = TRUE), 
                       "Firm" = head(LETTERS, 5), 
                       "Exporter"= sample(c("Yes", "No"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                        stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

levels(test.df1$Exporter) <- c(levels(test.df1$Exporter), ' ')
test.df1$Exporter[test.df1$Year == 2018] <- " "
test.df1

#   Year Firm Exporter
#1  2019    A       No
#2  2018    B         
#3  2018    C         
#4  2019    D       No
#5  2018    E         
#6  2018    A         
#7  2019    B       No
#8  2020    C       No
#9  2019    D       No
#10 2019    E      Yes
#11 2019    A       No
#12 2018    B         
#13 2019    C       No
#14 2018    D         
#15 2019    E       No
#16 2019    A       No
#17 2019    B      Yes
#18 2018    C         
#19 2018    D         
#20 2020    E       No
```